# How to rescale and save an BufferedImage

Tags: java, image, scaling

I got a BufferedImage and want to rescale it before saving it as an jpg/png.

I got the following code:

```
private BufferedImage rescaleTo(BufferedImage img,int minWidth,int minHeight) {
    BufferedImage buf = toBufferedImage(img.getScaledInstance(minWidth, minHeight, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
    BufferedImage ret = new BufferedImage(buf.getWidth(null),buf.getHeight(null),BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    return ret;
}

public BufferedImage toBufferedImage(Image img) {
    BufferedImage ret = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(null),img.getHeight(null),BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g2 = ret.createGraphics();
    g2.drawImage(img,0,0,null);
    return ret;
}

public String saveTo(BufferedImage image,String URI) throws UtilityException {
    try {
        if(image == null)
            System.out.println("dododod");
        ImageIO.write(image, _type, new File(URI));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new UtilityException(e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    return URI;
}
```

But as an result I just get a black picture. It must have to do with the rescaling as when I skip it I can save the expected picture.

Answer (score 0):

As a test, set _type="png" and also use file extension .png when you make the call to ImageIO.write(image, _type, new File(URI));. I had issues like you describe and I started writing type PNG and all works fine.  Unfortunately, I never went back to debug why I could not write type JPG, GIF etc.

Comment: as I stated in the comment, not rescaling it works fine. But I'll try yours maybe there is some real wierdish conflict after rescaling.